# What effects does the mpicc/openmp flag -Dparallel have?

Tags: mpi, openmp, openmpi

i ran into a problem with the flag -Dparallel (which we use in our code to enable parallel parts). When i use it, i dont get more then one OpenMP Thread anymore.

Remark: We are running MPI/OpenMP hyrbrid code.

A short code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"

#ifdef _OPENMP
    #include <omp.h>
#else
    #define omp_get_num_threads() 0
    #define omp_get_thread_num() 0
#endif

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int nthreads, thread_id;
  int rank, size, provided;

  MPI_Init_thread(&argc, &argv, MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED, &provided); /* starts MPI */

  MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank); /* get current process id */
  MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size); /* get number of processes */

  #pragma omp parallel private(nthreads, thread_id)
  {
    nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
    thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();

    if (thread_id == 0)
      printf("This is rank %d with %d threads.\n", rank,nthreads);
  }

  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

If i compiled it with `mpicc -o example -fopenmp example.c` the output shows:

```
$ mpirun -np 2 ./example
This is rank 1 with 6 threads.
This is rank 0 with 6 threads.
```

As expected.

If i use the flag `-Dparallel` (whole line: `mpicc -Dparallel -o example_parallel -fopenmp example.c` )

The output says:

```
$ mpirun -np 2 ./example_parallel 
This is rank 0 with 1 threads.
This is rank 1 with 1 threads.
```

Why does `-Dparallel` limits the OpenMP Threadfs to 1? Where can i find documentation for this?

for the sake of completeness:

- mpirun (Open MPI) 1.4.1
- gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) 4.4.3

EDIT (maybe the solution): I just testet to compile it using:

```
mpicc -Dparallel=parallel -o example_parallel -fopenmp example.c
```

it works as expected. So i guess, -Dparallel just messes up the `#pragma omp parallel`. Am i right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With most C compilers, `-D` is an option to define the value of a preprocessor macro symbol. With `-Dparallel` you define a preprocessor symbol called `parallel` but with an empty value. As preprocessing is always done before the code is further parsed by the compiler, all occurrences of `parallel` in your code are replaced by an empty string and `#pragma omp parallel private(...)` becomes `#pragma omp private(...)`. The compiler likely ignores the resulting invalid pragma.

Drop `-Dparallel` from the command line. If you need to be able to compile different parts of the code conditionally, then use another preprocessor symbol, for example `BUILD_PARALLEL`, e.g.:

```
#if defined(BUILD_PARALLEL)
 ... parallel code ...
#else
 ... serial code ...
#endif
```

**Never** use preprocessor symbols with names that match language keywords. Using `-Dparallel=parallel` is an **awful hack** to both have the `parallel` preprocessor symbol defined and still have it retain its original meaning.

Comment: You are right. Thx. `-Dparallel=parallel` was not meant as solution, but as proof that this is the problem.